# SQL stored procedure stored in svn?

Tags: sql, svn, stored-procedures

Is there a way to backup/track changes to SQL stored procedures in SVN or any other method for tracking changes to SQL?  I am using SQL 2008 and am not a DBA but am in charge of a small companies database.

TIA,

Brian Enderle

Comment: Stored procedures are just text. Why would you be concerned about not being able to track it in SVN?

Answer (score 4):

You might try [Red Gate's SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/) and [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) to track changes.

Answer (score 2):

We write procs and save them in Subversion as scripts. You check in each version of the script and then you can easily see previos versions or do a diff between them. If youwant to reduce unnecessary diffs from formatting, get a SQL formatting tool and have everyone format the same way before check in.

All SQL code should be handled this way not just procs. We store table strutures, views etc in Subversion. Of course with tables you havea create script and then alter table table scripts for each change in order, so that you don't wipe our tables with existing data by doing a drop and recreate. We also script out inserts to lookup tables to make them easier to port to other servers as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in svn, but it will have difficulty tracking **exact** changes if members of your team use different tools to write sql: postgresql seems to be particularly bad at formatting sql. You could consider using a free formatter: Eddie Awad lists some here:

http://awads.net/wp/2005/12/12/format-your-sql-the-easy-way/

Committing your code to source control depends on how you arrange your projects: your scripts could exist in a "misc" folder in an eclipse/visual studio project, or directly committed to svn via TortoiseSVN.

Comment: How do I tell SVN and/or SQL to track these changes?  I am the only one making changes (at least for now) but would still like to see when/why I made changes.  These changes typically go along with a software changes so it would be nice to check in the SP change along with the code change.

Comment: Yes, add the SProc creation script to your source-control system.  You can simply add it as another text file.

Comment: So are you saying I have to store the sp off to the hard drive as a text file?

Comment: Yes, that's my suggestion. Alternatively you could look into one of the tools suggested by OptillectTeam.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions for you (which I have both used myself):

1. you can use [ScriptDB](http://scriptdb.codeplex.com/) in order to extract the database schema to your file system and then commit it to svn. I actually set up a scheduled task which invokes ScriptDB every night and then commits the folder to svn (which only commits actually modified files) automatically.
2. If you are using VS2010 you can open a database project and synchronize it periodically with your database via the schema compare option from the data menu. After that you can commit your changes via tortoiseSVN or Ankh directly from VS.